# Conductors vs insulators with static electricity

Tags: electrostatics, electricity

I hope I can make this clear enough: I am trying to understand: what are the rules/constraints regarding to the materials that can produce static electricity?

I'll start with what I know about conductors and insulators: Conductors are materials that have high electron mobility - meaning - electrons can fairly easily travel between atoms. As such, they can be a means of electric current. Insulators are the opposite.

Wikipedia states:

> A static electric charge can be created whenever two surfaces contact and have worn and separated, and at least one of the surfaces has a high resistance to electric current (and is therefore an electrical insulator).

And [here](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-conductors-not-produce-static-electricity) I read:

> Because to get static charge the two rubbing bodies must be of two different nature's=
> Bodies which have tendency to give up electrons and become +ly charged like our human body, hair, fur, glass etc.
> Another bodies which have tendency to gain electrons and become -vely charged like copper ,gold,brass ,silver , wax etc
> So to produce static charge two opposite nature bodies to be rub.

From the second quote, I understand that two conductors can't create static electricity because they are of the "same nature" - they tend to gain electrons. It's not really their low resistance that disallows them to be statically charged. But from wikipedia, it sounds that the property that is needed to have static electricity is "low resistance".

Can someone explain this?